# Trouble while giving input from tex.sprint function to another function in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, strings, lua, luacode, directlua

I have the set.lua file with the following code.

```lua
local Set = {}   --module      
local mt = {} --metatable
    function Set.new (l)   
        local set = {}
        setmetatable(set, mt)
        for _, v in ipairs(l) 
        do set[v] = true --table keys are elements of sets having boolean value true.
          end 
        return set
      end
    function Set.union (a, b)
        local res = Set.new{}
        for k in pairs(a) do res[k] = true end
        for k in pairs(b) do res[k] = true end
        return res
      end
    function Set.tostring (set)
        local l = {}    
        for e in pairs(set) do
          if set[e] then
          l[#l + 1] = tostring(e)
          end
        end
        return "{" .. table.concat(l, ", ") .. "}"
      end
  return Set
```

Then there is luaset.sty file with the following code.

```
\ProvidesPackage{luaset}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local st = require "set"
function union(s,t)
local s=st.new(s)
local t=st.new(t)
local v= st.union(s,t)
return tex.sprint(st.tostring(v))
end
function setprint(s)
s=st.new(s)
return tex.sprint("\\{" .. st.tostring(s) .. "\\}")
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\setPrint}[1]{\directlua{setprint(#1)}}
\newcommand{\setUnion}[2]{\directlua{union(#1,#2)}}
\endinput
```

The Tex file which is compiled using LuaTeX or LuaHBTeX has the following input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaset}
\begin{document}
\def\S{{'a','b','c',10}} % declaring set S
\def\T{{'d','e','f',10,20}}  % declaring set T
 \(S= \setPrint{\S}\)\\  % printing set S
\(T=\setPrint{\T}\) \\ % printing set T
\def\V{\setUnion{\S}{\T}} %  union of S and T
 \(V= \setPrint{\V}\) % printing set V
\end{document}
```

This gets compiled. However the last line in TeX file does not give the expected output. Note that simply `\V` gives correct set of strings. So in order to solve this, I need to modify `set.print` function in `luaset.sty` file. I can't figure out what changes to be made. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The macro `\setUnion` already prints its result.  You don't need an extra `\setPrint` macro.

Comment: That is true. But I want to add curly braces. I can also concatenate curly braces but it gives problems while nesting. For example , taking union of 3 or more sets. Is it possible to avoid printing in `\setUnion` and just printing with `\setPrint` command. As function should return something in LuaTeX, I can't find  alternative for using `tex.sprint`

Comment: Do the two `for` loops in the `Set.union` function really do the job of creating a new Lua table that's the union of the elements in the two constituent sets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mix TeX macros and Lua values.  This always calls for trouble because you somehow have to remove formatting from strings to make them digestible for Lua which almost always goes wrong.

Let me propose this alternative.  First of all I parse the set as a string from TeX, this also solves the XY problem that you were asking for earlier: [Error when Metatable is set for global environment in Lua LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537582/error-when-metatable-is-set-for-global-environment-in-lua-latex)

Then I implement the set operations similar to yours, but every set operation apart from `__tostring` returns a Lua table and not a formatted string.

The macro interface does not use macros to store the results of set operations, but the user passes in names which are then used to keep track of the sets at the Lua end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
Set = {} -- module
local mt = {
    __tostring = function(self)
        return "\\{" .. table.concat(table.sortedkeys(self), ", ") .. "\\}"
    end
}

function Set.new(str)
    str = str or ""
    local set = {}
    for v in utilities.parsers.iterator(str) do
        set[v] = true
    end
    return setmetatable(set, mt)
end

function Set.union(...)
    local sets = table.pack(...)
    local union = {}
    for _, set in ipairs(sets) do
        for e in pairs(set) do
            union[e] = true
        end
    end
    return setmetatable(union, mt)
end

sets = {} -- global set registry
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\setNew[2]{%
    \directlua{%
        sets[\luastringN{#1}] = Set.new(\luastringN{#2})
    }%
}

\newcommand\setUnion[3]{%
    \directlua{%
        sets[\luastringN{#1}] = Set.union(sets[\luastringN{#2}],
                                          sets[\luastringN{#3}])
    }%
}

\newcommand\setPrint[1]{%
    \directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(sets[\luastringN{#1}]))}%
}

\begin{document}

\setNew{S}{a,b,c,10}
\setNew{T}{d,e,f,10,20}

\setUnion{R}{S}{T}

\setPrint{S}\par
\setPrint{T}\par
\setPrint{R}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Since the `luacode` package is loaded, one could also replace `"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{...}}"` with `\luastringN{...}`. (The `N` stands for "no expansion.)

Comment: @Mico Thanks, that makes it a lot less cluttered.

Comment: Where can I find references for command `utilities.parsers.iterator`?

Comment: @user61681 Maybe in the [CLD manual](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf) of ConTeXt, but I usually learn about these things by reading the source.

Comment: Source of LuaTeX or Context? I am curious specifically for `utilities.parsers.iterator`  command. Thanks.

Comment: @user61681 The LaTeX package is called [`lualibs`](https://github.com/latex3/lualibs) but that is essentially just ConTeXt utilities that were copied and pasted.  The definition of `utilities.parsers.iterator` is here: https://github.com/latex3/lualibs/blob/12d08ae98457679fff9511ef52ef761c898f4762/lualibs-util-prs.lua#L677-L698

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply.