# Setting Environment while defining complex numbers in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode, directlua

My question is inspired from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537953/trouble-while-giving-input-from-tex-sprint-function-to-another-function-in-luate) question that I asked earlier. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip,luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
M = {}         -- the module
complex = {} -- global complex numbers registry
local mt = {} --metatable for complex numbers
   function new (r, i)
       local cp = {}
        cp = {r=r, i=i}
        return setmetatable(cp,mt)
      end
      M.new = new        -- add 'new' to the module
    function M.op (...)
    local _ENV = complex
        return ...
      end  
      function M.add (c1, c2)
        return new(c1.r + c2.r, c1.i + c2.i)
      end
      function M.tostring (c)
        return string.format("(%g,%g)", c.r, c.i) --to avoid +-
      end
    mt.__tostring = M.tostring
    mt.__add = M.add
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\cpxNew[2]{%
    \directlua{%
        complex[\luastringN{#1}] = M.new(#2)
    }%
}
\newcommand\cpxPrint[1]{%
    \directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(complex[\luastringN{#1}]))}%
}

\newcommand\cpxOp[1]{%
    \directlua{%
        tex.print(tostring(M.op(#1)))
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\cpxNew{a}{3,4}
\cpxPrint{a} \par
\cpxOp{complex.a + complex.a} \par
%\cpxOp{a+a}
\end{document}
```

It gets compiled. I get expected output too, except for the commented last command `\cpxOp{a+a}`. When I un-comment it, I get the error (arithmetic on nil value). I need such thing for setting metatables. I expect the answer (6,8). However, I am getting nil. The previous command `\cpxOp{complex.a +complex.a}` gives expected answer. What is the problem with the function `M.op(...)`. I have set up local `_ENV` to complex and so I expect to get same answer as `\cpxOp{complex.a + complex.a}` for the command `\cpxOp{a+a}`. This does not happen. What may be the reason? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Changing `_ENV` doesn't have the effect you are looking for because Lua is not a macro language. If you had written `return a` instead of `return ...` in `M.op`, Lua  would have used `complex.a`, but in your example the global `a` is looked up before `M.op` is even called. So the new `_ENV` isn't in effect at that point.

Comment: So how to evaluate `...` in the environment complex?

Comment: The question isn't where `...` is evaluated, it is in which scope `a` appears. So if you would want this, you would have to set `local _ENV=complex` in the `\directlua` block in `\cpxOp`

Comment: How to set `local_ENV = complex` in the `\directlua` block?

Answer (score 2):

Your macro `\cpxNew` is registering an element inside the `complex` table (in your case, `complex.a` or `complex["a"]`). If you call `a`, you get `nil` as it is an undefined element. A workaround is defining a new command so you have not to write `complex`

### EDIT

If you don't mind breaking things, you can equal `complex` and `_G` (global variable).

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    M = {}        -- the module
    complex = _G -- global complex numbers registry
    local mt = {} --metatable for complex numbers

    function new (r, i)
    local cp = {}
    cp = {r=r, i=i}
    return setmetatable(cp,mt)
    end

    M.new = new        -- add 'new' to the module

    function M.op (...)
    local _ENV = complex
    return ...
    end

    function M.tostring (c)
    return string.format("(%g,%g)", c.r, c.i) --to avoid +-
    end
    mt.__tostring = M.tostring
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\cpxNew[2]{%
    \directlua{%
    complex[\luastringN{#1}] = M.new(#2)
}%
}
\newcommand\cpxPrint[1]{%
\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(complex[\luastring{#1}]))}%
}


\newcommand\cpxOp[1]{%
\directlua{%
tex.print(tostring(M.op(#1)))
}%
}
%Workaround
\newcommand\cpxOpp[1]{%
    \directlua{%
    tex.print(tostring(M.op(complex[\luastring{#1}])))
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\cpxNew{a}{3,4}
\cpxPrint{a}
\cpxOp{a+a}
\end{document}
```

Now your code works.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I expect something different. I have modified the question. Have a look at it.

Comment: See again. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Can there be a better way out of running it in complex environment rather than polluting global space?

Comment: I get with this code : \cpxOp ...rectlua {tex.print(tostring(M.op(#1))) }
l.51 \cpxOp{a+a}
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.